# Using addition to calculate cubes in order.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I discovered that S_n = n^2 when dealing with the smallest odd numbers and also found a small connection for cubes. I understand the squares, but can anyone explain why this is happening with the cubes? (It doesn't work for the first addition.)

1 + 7 = 8

8 + (7) + 12 =27

27 + (7 + 12) + 18 = 64

64 + (7 + 12 + 18) + 24 = 125

125 + (7 + 12 + 18 + 24) + 30 = 216

To get the next natural cube (n^3) you add everything, that we added to the last one and also apparently (n-1)*6.

(There's a similar thing with the fourth power, but it's one step deeper, which is logical, I guess.)

Answer (score 2):

What you have is
$$n^3 + (1+6(1+2+3+4+\dots+n))$$
$$= n^3+\left(1+6\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$
$$= n^3 + 1 + 3n^2+3n $$
$$ = n^3+3n^2+3n+1$$
$$ = (n+1)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(n + 1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. So in order to get the next cube, you have to add $3n^2 + 3n + 1$ to the last one.

You decided to look for a pattern in the addition, so let's find $3(n + 1)^2 + 3(n + 1) + 1 = 3n^2 + 9n + 11$. So if you want to find the term you need to add to the term which you have to add, then you've got to add $6n + 6$.

So there you have it. There is a linear relationship between the addition terms of the cubic.

Following the same logic, there will be a quadratic relationship between the addition terms of the quartic, and so on.